# CMake/QtCreator/CPack build directory location

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

At the beginning of my develeopment I used KDevelop, and `MainDir/build` directory for building my generated stuff. After adding some Qt stuff, I changed to QtCreator, and accepted its convention to use `MainDir-build` for generated stuff. My experience is that `cmake ..; make; make doc; make package` works fine in the first case. In the second case `cmake ../MainDir; make; make doc` works fine. However, `make package` results in `make: *** No rule to make target 'package'.  Stop` The reason is outside my cmake files, the first method still works fine. Any help?

Directory structure; in the first case:

```
MainDir
  -- build
  CMakeLists.txt
```

In the second case

```
MainDir
  CMakeLists.txt
MainDir-build
```

Comment: It looks like you did `mkdir build; cd build; cmake ../MainDir; ...`  That would imply that you arn't in `MainDir/build` and that your `CMakeLists.txt` may be somewhere else.  What is your folder structure (including build dir, source dir, and where CMakeLists.txt is)?